# importing packages in android

Tags: android, package

Do I have to include the activities to my app's Manifest file from the package which are imported to my android app.?
thanks

Logcat error:

`01-13 02:28:08.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 02:28:08.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.s.android.test/com.s.android.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.s.android.test.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.s.android.test-2.apk]
01-13 02:28:08.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)`

[Error >paste.org](http://paste.org/pastebin/api/27440)

Comment: @rahul: Can you pls be clear, what do you want, show with a clear example?

Comment: I have an android app.from which users can login to a blog using their facebook account...          So i had used the classes provided by the facebook people...now its a package in my app. I have a single activity in my app.(MainActivity)...But the application is crashing when I start it ..!

Comment: @rahul: can you post the error message in Your Logcat, pls????

Comment: thanks..I have the error pasted in the above link...

Comment: @rahul: can you pls paste your entire code in pastebin.com, let me review it?????????????????/

Comment: http://paste.org/pastebin/api/27441    --->my app's main activity class...

Comment: http://paste.org/pastebin/api/27442  --->Manifest file

Comment: the package path is not shown in the manifest...!

Comment: what do you say...have a solution..?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeMain/index.html) states:

> Currently, an application must declare
>   in its manifest any components or
>   resources that it is using from a
>   library project.

So if I understood your question correctly, yes you have to redeclare the activities.

Comment: Thanks..but when I edit the Manifest file in the Eclipse....it only shows the single package..ie my app's package..Now I doubt I had done some thing wrong to include the package in my app. Have any sample code or tutorials which can tell me how to work with packages?

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.s.android.test.MainActivity

To me this implies the package name in your Manifest isn't correctly defined for that Activity.

Edit:

You need to just check the base package and the path to your activity match the actual package your activity is in. Eg:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name=".SecretService" . . . >
```

The SecretService class would thus be found in com.example.project.SecretService (Obviously the example shows this for a Service but the same is true for an Activity.) You should probably also read more about the fundatmentals here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html